# Choose distinct colors based on Custom Properties

Tags: 3d-view, properties

Is there a way to assign a distinct "random" color to a mesh based on the string-value of one of its "Custom Properties"? I am most interested in having this color visible in the 3D viewport to distinguish objects based on their properties while editing a scene.

I'm not sure whether the solution should be based on shading or not. The viewport "solid mode" view with "random" color assignment is close to what I want except that it chooses a separate color for each object rather than for a group with the same property.

For example, supposing that I would have a large number of meshes each with a property "country" and I wanted each mesh with value "australia" to be one color, each with value "usa" to be another color, and so on.

Comment: Hello, would it be OK if you represented each country with a number instead of a string of characters ?

Comment: That would be workable yep. I'd probably then have two attributes, "country" and "country_num", that correspond with one for human consumption and one for internal use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the latest Blender Version (2.92+) and custom properties :

1. [Download the latest version](https://builder.blender.org/download/) (At least 2.92+, which is currently in Beta but should be officially released pretty soon).
2. Select your object, and create your custom property, named "country".
3. In the *value* field, you can input a string of characters. Don't forget to press *OK* to validate your change.

[image]

4. Create another property, let's call it hash. Keep the min and max between 0 and 1.

[image]

5. Right click in the field and choose *Add Driver*. Delete the target variable, check *Self* and type `hash(self["country"])%1000/1000`. This will generate a (kinda) random number between 0 and 1 depending on the string inside the *country* property. The hash provides the same output if 2 inputs are the same.

[image]

6. Important : You have to enable python scripts globally for this to work. Go to *Edit > Preferences > Save & Load* and enable *Auto run python scripts*. You can add your *Downloads* folder for security, that way downloaded files won't execute custom scripts automatically.

[image]

7. Add a material to your object. Use this layout :

[image]

Add an *Attribute* node set to *Object* type, and input the *hash* custom property name. Link it to a *Combine HSV* node to create a random hue.

8. Result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer! This seems ideal. The hash presumably gives me consistent color choices for the same string which seems like a big plus (even though it may not choose the most visually distinct colours for the data I happen to use.) Good trade-off.

Comment: You could use a different method than hash I guess :) You can also add another property and use it in the shader as an offset to the hash value to fine-tune it

Comment: I suppose that one could imagine a future version of Blender where there is a node that takes a string property directly and outputs its hash value, so that it would not be necessary to manually create the hash properties with scripts (e.g. if there would be many different properties to hash.) That's assuming nodes can convert from strings to numbers?

Comment: Maybe an elegant solution would even be for the Converter->Math node to have a "Conversion" function called Hash that hashes a string input?

Comment: I looked for something like that at first, but internally I don't think you can even feed string data into the shader pipeline. It only works with float Vectors of size 4 as far as I know. Not a developer though :)

Comment: I am digging into the source code... it's as good an excuse as any to start learning how Blender works under the hood...

Comment: Turns out that the shader pipeline can handle strings, e.g. the "Density Attribute" port of "Principled Volume" shader node. I'm not sure what the neatest way to fit a Hash operation into the existing shaders would be e.g. maybe it should be separate from the Math converter (that purely uses float ports.)

Comment: I would plug it into a white noise node and see what comes out :)

Comment: Great pointer! If the white noise node took a string input then that would be the very thing.